# Filler word or phrase to skip details that aren't important

Tags: colloquial

Is there a word or a phrase in German to cut off the sentence when talking about something but not all the details are important.

Example in English: "Last night, we went out to that place for drinks [and what not] [and so on]."

Here the details aren't interesting enough to mention or not important, so its like "et cetera" to skip and get to the point.

I usually find my self saying "Und So.." not sure if that is correct.

Comment: Und so is perfectly fine and applicable in virtually any situation.

Comment: @infinitezero Das ist m.E. die Antwort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As in English, there is a variety of colloquial options, with nuances in meaning. Here are some:

- *und so weiter* ("and so on")
- *und so* ("and so on")
- *et cetera* ("et cetera")
- *und haste nicht gesehen* (rather informal, might also be regional, "and what not")
- *und, und, und* (also rather informal, roughly "and even more")
- *mit allem, was dazu gehört* ("with all the bells and whistles")
- *mit allem drum und dran* (more informal, "with all the bells and whistles")